# How to grep all the strings which end with '.txt'

Tags: grep

I need to find all the strings which end with '.txt' inside text file.
I tried:

```
grep 'txt$' myFile
```

But it gives out whole lines, not only the strings which end with '.txt'

Comment: You'll need `-w` for words and `-n` if you want results on their own line. `-i` will do a case-insensitive search and `-c` will return the number of times that word appeared in the file. A regex will be needed to get "things with a .txt suffix", making `-i` unnecessary. Once you see the power of grep, you'll wonder how you ever tolerated most text search functions for so long …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to list *only* the matched "strings," you should use the `-o` option of `grep`:

```
grep -o '\w*\.txt\b' myFile
```

or

```
grep -Eo '\w+\.txt\b' myFile
```

The man page explains this option like this:

> -o, --only-matching
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
> with each such part on a separate output line.

However, you need to define your understanding of "strings." I assume a "string" is something like a "word" described in the man page:

> The symbols \< and \> respectively match the empty string at the
> beginning and end of a word. The symbol \b matches the empty string at
> the edge of a word, and \B matches the empty string provided it's not
> at the edge of a word. The symbol \w is a synonym for [_[:alnum:]] and
> \W is a synonym for [^_[:alnum:]].

In the above example, the two-letter sequences mean this:

| Seq. | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\w` | any alphanumeric character |
| `\w*` | any number (0 or more) of alphanumeric characters |
| `\w+` | any number (1 or more) of alphanumeric characters (extended regular expression) |
| `\.` | the period (`.`) character itself (`.` has special meaning and it should be escaped) |
| `\b` | match end of the word (no more alphanumeric characters after the string `txt`) |

---

Note: The `$` character you used in your question means "end-of-line" and it will cause to match strings `txt` than happen to appear *only* at end of lines.

Comment: Note that `+` is literal in BRE - to make it a quantifier you will need to use `grep -E`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver for the warning! :)